# Is it true that $\mathbb{E}\{X_n\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_m\}\Rightarrow\mathbb{E}\{X_n|\mathcal{F}_m\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_m|\mathcal{F}_m\}=X_m$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value, filtrations

Given a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n}$ and a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n}$, is it true that, for $m\leq n$,
$$\mathbb{E}\{X_n\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_m\}\Rightarrow\mathbb{E}\{X_n|\mathcal{F}_m\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_m|\mathcal{F}_m\}=X_m$$?
**If the answer is 'yes', how can one prove this?**

Comment: Consider the problem for small $n$ first and see what happens.

Comment: I have tried to assume $n=2$ and $m=1$; however, starting from $\mathbb{E}\{X_2\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_1\}$, I cannot see which could be the relation between $\mathbb{E}\{X_2|\mathcal{F}_1\}$ and $\mathbb{E}\{X_1|\mathcal{F}_1\}=X_1$. I am sorry...Could you please help me by adding some hint? @BrevanEllefsen